# How to record voice using Flash and save to PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

The following are done work
**Get WAV file => OK**

```
private function renderWav(src, convertToMp3 = false) {
    WaveFile.writeBytesToWavFile(myWavFile, myWavData, 44100, 2, 16)       
}
```

**Convert to MP3 => OK**

```
private function makeIntoMp3(wav) {
    mp3Encoder = new ShineMP3Encoder(wav);
    mp3Encoder.start();
}
```

**save MP3 file to Client => OK**

```
private function onWavClick(e:MouseEvent) {
   new FileReference().save(mp3Encoder.mp3Data, "MyAudio.mp3");
}
```

Above, I can get a MP3 file in client side but on my problem that save to Server side(PHP)

**Save to server side => Fail**

```
public function makeMP3File() {
   var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables;
   urlVariables.mp3Data = mp3Encoder.mp3Data;           
   var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('upload.php');
   req.data = urlVariables;
   req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   loader.load(req);
}
```

**My PHP Code**

```
function strean2audio($audioStream, $filename)
{
   $file = fopen($filename . '.mp3', "wb");
   fwrite($file, $audioStream);
   fclose($file);
}
```

I was a ActionScript rookie, don't know which part error, ***thanks for your help!***

Comment: The snippet of PHP you provide doesn't actually handle the upload. Post some more PHP please.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I didn't use **move_uploaded_file()** to handle the upload job, only use **fwrite()** to write a file to my server, It can works on the data is a string but not audio stream, Or **mp3Encoder.mp3Data** is not a audio stream( I have no idea )

Comment: I get a Invalid audio file in my server ( The audio file is invalid or corrupted )

Comment: I refer to [**VOCWordToYourMp3**](https://github.com/ivanp/VOCWordToYourMp3) to modify my program and [_save MP3 file to Client_ **OK**] but when I sent **mp3Encoder.mp3Data** to my server, It was Fail.

Comment: maybe I just don't get it what is **mp3Encoder.mp3Data**?(audio stream Or tmp file name Or some what...)

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to solve my problem ( For your reference )

// FLASH make MP3 file to server

```
public function makeMP3File() {
  var sba:ByteArray = mp3Encoder.mp3Data;    **//to ByteArray**
  var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('upload.php');
  req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
  req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  req.data = sba;           
  var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
}
```

// PHP server side

```
function strean2audio($name, $spec, $userId=0) {
    $audio_content = file_get_contents("php://input");  **//get RAW POST**
    $file = fopen($audio_file_name . '.mp3', "wb");
    fwrite($file, $audio_content);
    fclose($file);
}
```

**conclusion**

**recorder.MP3 -> ByteArray -> URLRequest -> URLLoader -> PHP -> ByteArray -> MP3**

refrence link : [Voice Recorder + Server Upload](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/788647)

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to do something like you do. What is "php://input"? Could you please help?

Comment: **php://input** allows you to read raw POST data. It is a less memory intensive alternative to **$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA** and does not need any special **php.ini** directives.

Comment: @xenophon566 - I am currently in the process of looking into doing this myself. From what I can tell from your code (*being relatively new to ActionScript*) you are not using **streaming** your audio data through to **php://input** and using *fwrite* to save this as an mp3? Or do you have some sort of Encoding going on in ActionScript also? **Thanks**